# What is the standard smooth structure of a disjoint union of smooth manifolds?

Tags: smooth-manifolds

I am following Lee in his introduction to smooth manifolds page 442. He explains that if $\{M_j\}_{j = 1}^\infty$ is a countable collection of smooth $n$-manifolds with or without boundary and let $M = \coprod_{j=1}^\infty M_j$, then there is an isomorphism of the de Rham cohomology groups $H^p(M)$ and $\prod_{j=1}^\infty H^p(M_j)$.

But what is the standard smooth structure that turns $\coprod_{j=1}^\infty M_j$ into a smooth manifold?

Comment: I think $C^\infty \left (\coprod_i M_i \right)$ is simply $\prod_i C^\infty(M_i)$.

Comment: Every open subset of $\coprod_i M_i$ is of the form $\coprod_i U_i$ with $U_i$ open in $M_i$, so you can reconstruct the entire sheaf of smooth functions from that.

Comment: @pyon How about taking the disjoint union of the smooth structures of each $M_j$, $\mathcal{A} = \coprod_j \mathcal{A}_j$? Do you think this would make a good smooth structure?

Comment: A smooth structure on $M$ is first and foremost a presheaf, i.e., a contravariant functor from the topology of $M$ (as a lattice, i.e., as a particular small category) that sends each open $U \subset M$ to the ring of smooth functions $C^\infty(U)$. This satisfies a couple of gluing conditions making it, in fact, a sheaf.

Comment: It is not clear to me what a disjoint union of functors should be, though.

Comment: Yes, $\coprod_j \mathcal A_j$ is what you want.

Comment: @LeeMosher Sorry if I sound stupid. But do you mean the disjoint union of atlases?